# Three points $P,Q,R$ on a circle $O$. Draw circles with diameters $PQ,QR, RP$. Probability when $O$ lies inside the three circles drawn?

Tags: probability, contest-math

Sample three random points $P,Q,R$ on a unit circle $O$. Draw circles with diameters $PQ,QR,RP$. Find the probability when origin $O$ lies inside at least one of the three circles drawn?

There is a well know problem where we are simply looking for probability when $O$ is within $\triangle PQR$ and the probability is $\frac{1}{4}$. but is there a solution when we are looking for the probability when origin lies within circles with diameters $PQ,QR,RP$?

[Probability that the center of a circle lies within three chosen points on a circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3262965/probability-that-the-center-of-a-circle-lies-within-three-chosen-points-on-a-cir)

[What is the probability that the center of the circle is contained within the triangle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268635/what-is-the-probability-that-the-center-of-the-circle-is-contained-within-the-tr?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will first look at probability of $O$ not falling in any of the $3$ circles.

As we are taking all $3$ segments as diameter of $3$ circles, their radii (say, $r$ for any one of them) has to be less than the perp distance from $O$ to the segment (say, $h$) for $O$ not to be in any of the circles.

Now, $r^2 + h^2 = 1^2$ given unit circle. As the radius has to be less than the distance from $O$ to the segment, $r \leq h \implies r \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} (\leq 45^0$ angle).

**So the segment should subtend an angle of $\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ at $O$.**

If we take point $P$ randomly on the unit circle, the probability of the next point $Q$  being within angle $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to it (on either side of it) will be $\frac{\pi}{2\pi} = \frac{1}{2}$.

Say points $P$ and $Q$ subtend an angle of $\theta (\leq \frac{\pi}{2})$ at $O$. Then point $R$ can be within $(\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta)$ angle on either side of $P$ or $Q$. But it can also fall between point $P$ and $Q$ hence the probability of point $R$ satisfying the condition such that point $O$ is not within the $3$ circles $= \displaystyle \frac{2(\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta) + \theta}{2\pi} = \frac{\pi - \theta}{2\pi}$ where $0 \lt \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.

The probability for point $R = \frac{1}{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/2} (\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\theta}{2\pi}) d\theta = \frac{2}{\pi} (\frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{\pi}{16}) = \frac{3}{8}$.

So probability that none of the circles have point $O = \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{3}{8} = \frac{3}{16}$.

So desired probability $ = 1 - \frac{3}{16} = \frac{13}{16}$